# How to use a pre-existing network in Docker Compose

Tags: docker

```
Docker version 20.10.16, build aa7e414

docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c

macOS Monterey
Version 12.2.1
MacBook Air (M1)
```

The following are the existing Docker networks:

```
NETWORK ID     NAME             DRIVER    SCOPE
53c30c122cc6   bridge           bridge    local
06f81782db26   host             host      local
eba839136a82   none             null      local
```

I want to create a new mongodb container and connect it to the existing bridge network shown above.

I tried different Compose files but none of them worked:

Approach 1)

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mongodb_container:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb_demo
    ports:
      - 27020:27017
    networks:
          - b
networks:
  b:
    external:
      name: bridge
```

Approach 2)

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mongodb_container:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb_demo
    ports:
      - 27020:27017
    networks:
      - bridge

networks:
  bridge:
    external: true
```

Approach 3)

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mongodb_container:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb_demo
    ports:
      - 27020:27017

networks:
  default:
    name: bridge
    external: true
```

All 3 approaches give me the following error:

> Starting mongodb_demo ... error
> ERROR: for mongodb_demo  network-scoped alias is supported only for
> containers in user defined networks
> ERROR: for mongodb_container  network-scoped alias is supported only
> for containers in user defined networks ERROR: Encountered errors
> while bringing up the project.

Answer (score 0):

Do not specify networks at the bottom on the docker-compose at all. Use `network_mode: bridge` for each service instead. Unlike customer-defined network, default bridge does not has DNS resolution for hostnames unless you specify `links:` between containers

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongodb_container:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27020:27017
    network_mode: bridge
    links:
      - another_service

  another_service:
    image: alpine
    network_mode: bridge
```

Comment: links are deprecated, you should use networks instead. 
https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

Comment: @AymaneELJahrani article recommends using "user-defined networks" instead of "links". This whole question is about how to use default bridge network!

Answer (score 0):

From official documentation

```
networks:
  network1:
    name: my-pre-existing-network
    external: true
```

To get the name of existing networks

```
docker network ls
```

Answer (score -2):

The only issue I see with all 3 approaches is indentation. `network` attribute is usable within the `services` tag and not within service_name which is mongodb_container in your case. Hence your code should look like:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    mongodb_container:
        image: mongo
        container_name: mongodb_demo
        ports:
            - 27020:27017
    networks:
        - bridge

networks:
    bridge:
        external: true
```